# Package Vue frontend in Go binary

Tags: go, heroku, gitlab-ci

I am trying to serve my frontend using the Gin framework. It is a small project which would make maintenance easier having it as a single binary.

The project structure looks like this:

```
Project
 |
 +-- backend
 |  |  
 |  +-- backend (binary)
 |    
 +-- frontend
 |  |  
 |  +-- dist
 |  |  
 |  +-- package.json
 |    
 +-- Procfile
 |    
 +-- .gitlab-ci.yml
```

Currently I am serving the fronend like this:

```
r.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("../frontend/dist", false)))
```

For local dev this works fine and I did not have any issues. If I deploy this with my gitlab-ci pipeline it fails as I do not upload the `../frontend/dist` directory. I looked at the [pkgr library](https://github.com/markbates/pkger) which should help me achieve my goal.

My issue is I can not get it to work with the Gin framework. Current snippet:

```
test := pkger.Dir("../frontend/dist")

r.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("../frontend/dist", false))) <- compiles but does not serve frontend
r.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile(test, false))) <- Does not compile
```

Is there an easier way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you deploy the project to Heroku (I supposed you are using Heroku because of the tag you are using) it compiles the Go to a binary.

The binary is running in the root folder of the project and `../frontend` is not in the same path as the development enviroment anymore.

Something like this:

```
Project
 |
 +-- backend
 |  |  
 |  +-- backend (binary)
 |    
 +-- frontend
 |  |  
 |  +-- dist
 |  |  
 |  +-- package.json
 |    
 +-- Procfile
 |    
 +-- .gitlab-ci.yml
 |
 +-- project binary <---- here
```

So the correct path is `./frontend/` (see one dot)

You can set an environment variable to set the correct path.

As you are using Vue, you can set for the development environment a dev-server with a proxy pointing to backend. Then when building for production you can make Vue compiles to a specific folder that is hardcoded and served by the backend.

Comment: Hi Lucas, thank you so much I have spent quite a few hours trying to get it to work without success! How does Heroku recognize to upload frontend/dist too though? It works but I do not understand why it is working.

Comment: Heroku uses your repo as project root folder... so you must consider using your repo root folder as you application root folder...And you define how it runs in the Procfile